# Need help figuring out what this anime manga where protagonist uses spirit feather was called

Tags: story-identification, anime

An old anime I'm trying to remember.

The main character uses a spirit blue feather that resembles his mother power and another that he has which is his dad’s power(never uses).

He has to fight certain monsters to upgrade his feather better,  at one point he fights an armored spider and almost dies absorbing its power into his feather. He  has a rabbit-like companion who all along was a god like creature.

He was an underdog who went through so much training,  and finally worked his way up to the top almost. Also, there are all these types of clans.

also to add on, he's part of a rare sky clan, I think. He trains with 6 other people at the dojo/school, who also have different powers. He became a god status pretty quick. You have to undergo a lot training to become a certain master.

Comment: Having found it, now tell us what it is!

Comment: It's great that you found the answer! Could you also share it to us by posting an answer on the text box down below? [Self-answering](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) is not only allowed, but it's also encouraged! By doing that, you're also contributing on here to help future readers :)